# How to detach and rebind kendo dropdown for cascading?

Tags: kendo-ui

I tried to set the `cascadeFrom` option like this: `$("#itemQty").data("kendoDropDownList").setOptions({ cascadeFrom: "category" });`

setOptions() is woking for other options like `template` but not for `cascadeFrom`. Anything else that i need to perform except refresh(). See the example at [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/japanwala/1v76Lg9f/4/). Here I tried to bind the third kendo dropdown with the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that

```
$("#itemQty").data("kendoDropDownList")._cascade();
```

works as you want after you set cascadeFrom by `setOptions()` method. However it's private method and can stop working in futher versions of Kendo.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1v76Lg9f/5/

Comment: it's working! just let me know how did you find it. From the kendo source code? I will mark it as an answer. Most of the people are striving to make connected drop-down in grid. This technique is relatively easy compared to making custom editor for cascading drop-drop.

Comment: I'm using Firebug and in you fiddle I've added line `console.log($("#itemQty").data("kendoDropDownList"));` to spy that object in console. Than it was just a guess suggested by function names :)